# VBScript - Create a dynamic variable name based on another variable's value

Tags: vbscript

I have stored the 'ServiceName' values in an excel file for parametrization (Code - Line 4).

```
Format in Excel: 
    ServiceName     (Header)
    EisOrdAmd
    EntCanAmd
```

I want to use dynamic variable names for the 3rd argument in 'fnExcQuery' function based on the parameters passed (Line 5), i.e., for the 1st loop the variable name should be 'strQuery_EisOrdAmd' and for the 2nd loop it should be 'strQuery_EntCanAmd'

```
1.  ststrQuery_EisOrdAmd = "Select * from EisOrdAmd"
2.  strQuery_EntCanAmd = "Select * from EntCanAmd"
3.  Do While (Not objRecordSet_TestData.EOF)
4.      strServiceName = Trim(objRecordSet_TestData.fields("ServiceName"))
5.      blnResponse_Request = fnExcQuery(strUser, strPwd, strQuery_<strServiceName>)            
        '1st Loop: strQuery_EisOrdAmd ; 2nd Loop: strQuery_EntCanAmd 
6.      objRecordSet_TestData.MoveNext
7.  Loop
```

How could I create dynamic variable name for the 3rd argument. I couldn't able to find a solution using vbscript, could you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `eval()` in other languages, you need to be very careful when executing dynamic code in this fashion. Having said that, you can use the `Execute()` function to execute a *string* as if it were a VBScript statement. In your case, you'd need to use this statement:

```
Execute "blnResponse_Request = fnExcQuery(strUser, strPwd, strQuery_" & strServiceName & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Eval or Execute but use a Dictionary:

```
Option Explicit

Dim dN : Set dN = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dN("AA") = "aa"
dN("BB") = "bb"
Dim sN
For Each sN In Split("AA CC BB")
    If dN.Exists(sN) Then
       WScript.Echo sN, dN(sN)
    Else
       WScript.Echo sN, "???"
    End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 31566748.vbs
AA aa
CC ???
BB bb
```

Comment: I couldn't able to match your solution with my query. Sorry if I am ignorant. As per your statement, you want me to create dictionary to store the variable name instead of creating dynamic variable name. The queries I have written (strQuery_EisOrdAmd, strEntCanAmd) are hardcoded in my .vbs file, but which query to be used during execution is given based on the input excel file. So I am bit confused to implement the dictionary logic in here. Could you pls help.